# Invalid JSON number '2L'. shard key being serialized to number but defined as string?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Exception:

```
System.FormatException: Invalid JSON number '2L'.
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonScanner.GetNumberToken(JsonBuffer buffer, Int32 firstChar)
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonScanner.GetNextToken(JsonBuffer buffer)
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonReader.PopToken()
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonReader.ReadBsonType()
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.BsonDocumentSerializer.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
```

Shard key definition, which is a composite key created by the constructor;

```
public string ShardKey { get; set; }
```

Query code:

```
    public virtual async Task<ICollection<City>>(City city)
    {
        string shardKey = city.CityNumber + city.ShortName;
        return await MongoDb.CitiesCollection.Aggregate().Match({
        "{ 'Time': { $elemMatch: { $eq: 0 } }," + " ShardKey: " + shardKey + " }")
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Why does this fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the value containing the number like:

```
" ShardKey: '" + shardKey + "' }"
```

with single quotation marks.

I haven't been able to find this documented anywhere though. But it makes the my integration test run so :)